onSuccess not running after link token is created
I've been trying to create a small app that differentiates between Zelle transactions and the actual balance. Of course in order to do that I need bank information. Thus, I am trying to integrate the plaid sdk into my react native ios app.
I am trying to follow this repo's implementation but I am struggling with one thing.
When my link token is created, I am struggling to get the onSuccess to run so I can have the exchange link token api get called. Does anyone know how I can do this in IOS?
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Button,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

import { create, open, dismissLink, LinkSuccess, LinkExit, LinkIOSPresentationStyle, LinkLogLevel } from 'react-native-plaid-link-sdk';

// Define the types for transactions
type Transaction = {
  id: string;
  amount: number;
  date: string; // ISO format date string
  type: 'credit' | 'debit';
};

// Mock data for demonstration purposes
const mockTransactions: Transaction[] = [
  // Add your transaction data here
];

const BalancePage: React.FC = () => {
  console.log('Rendering BalancePage');
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState<string>('month');
  const [filterFromPayout, setFilterFromPayout] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [lastPayoutDate, setLastPayoutDate] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [totalBalance, setTotalBalance] = useState<number>(0);
  const [zelleBalance, setZelleBalance] = useState<number>(0);
  const [linkToken, setLinkToken] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const handlePayout = () => {
    const payoutDate = new Date().toISOString();
    console.log(`Setting last payout date to: ${payoutDate}`);
    setLastPayoutDate(payoutDate);
    setFilterFromPayout(true);
  };


  const createLinkToken = useCallback(async () => {
    await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/create_link_token/`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ address: 'localhost:8000' })
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setLinkToken(data.link_token);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, [setLinkToken]);

  const createLinkTokenConfiguration = (token: string, noLoadingState: boolean = false) => {
    return {
      token: token,
      noLoadingState: noLoadingState,
    };
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect triggered. linkToken:', linkToken);
    if (linkToken === null) {
      console.log('Getting link token');
      createLinkToken();
    }
    if (linkToken) {
      const tokenConfig = createLinkTokenConfiguration(linkToken);
      create(tokenConfig)
    }
  }, [filterFromPayout, linkToken]);

  const createLinkOpenProps = () => {
    return {
      onSuccess: async (success: LinkSuccess) => {
        await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/exchange_link_token/`, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ public_token: success.publicToken }),
        })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      },
      onExit: (linkExit: LinkExit) => {
        console.log('Exit: ', linkExit);
        dismissLink();
      },
      iOSPresentationStyle: LinkIOSPresentationStyle.MODAL,
      logLevel: LinkLogLevel.ERROR,
    };
  };

  const handleOpenLink = () => {
    const openProps = createLinkOpenProps();
    open(openProps);
  };


  const filters = ['day', 'week', 'month', 'monthToDate'];

  const calculateBalances = () => {
    console.log('Calculating balances...');
    let filteredTransactions = filterTransactions(mockTransactions, filter);

    if (filterFromPayout && lastPayoutDate) {
      console.log(`Filtering transactions from last payout date: ${lastPayoutDate}`);
      filteredTransactions = filteredTransactions.filter(
        txn => new Date(txn.date) > new Date(lastPayoutDate)
      );
    }

    const balance = filteredTransactions.reduce((acc, txn) => {
      return txn.type === 'credit' ? acc + txn.amount : acc - txn.amount;
    }, 0);

    const zelleTxns = filteredTransactions.filter(txn => txn.type === 'debit'); // Assuming 'debit' as Zelle transactions
    const zelleTotal = zelleTxns.reduce((acc, txn) => acc + txn.amount, 0);

    console.log(`New total balance: ${balance}, New Zelle balance: ${zelleTotal}`);
    setTotalBalance(balance);
    setZelleBalance(zelleTotal);
  };

  const filterTransactions = (transactions: Transaction[], filter: string) => {
    console.log(`Filtering transactions with filter: ${filter}`);
    const now = new Date();
    return transactions.filter(txn => {
      const txnDate = new Date(txn.date);
      switch (filter) {
        case 'day':
          return isSameDay(now, txnDate);
        case 'week':
          return isSameWeek(now, txnDate);
        case 'month':
          return isSameMonth(now, txnDate);
        case 'monthToDate':
          return txnDate >= new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), 1);
        default:
          return true;
      }
    });
  };

  const isSameDay = (d1: Date, d2: Date) => {
    const result = d1.getDate() === d2.getDate() &&
      d1.getMonth() === d2.getMonth() &&
      d1.getFullYear() === d2.getFullYear();
    console.log(`Comparing dates: ${d1.toISOString()} and ${d2.toISOString()}. Same day: ${result}`);
    return result;
  }

  const isSameWeek = (d1: Date, d2: Date) => {
    const onejan = new Date(d1.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
    const week1 = Math.ceil((((d1.getTime() - onejan.getTime()) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay() + 1) / 7);
    const week2 = Math.ceil((((d2.getTime() - onejan.getTime()) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay() + 1) / 7);
    const result = week1 === week2 && d1.getFullYear() === d2.getFullYear();
    console.log(`Comparing dates: ${d1.toISOString()} and ${d2.toISOString()}. Same week: ${result}`);
    return result;
  };

  const isSameMonth = (d1: Date, d2: Date) => {
    const result = d1.getMonth() === d2.getMonth() && d1.getFullYear() === d2.getFullYear();
    console.log(`Comparing dates: ${d1.toISOString()} and ${d2.toISOString()}. Same month: ${result}`);
    return result;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Total Balance</Text>
      <Text style={styles.balance}>${totalBalance.toFixed(2)}</Text>

      <Text style={styles.subtitle}>Filters</Text>
      <View style={styles.filterContainer}>
        {filters.map(f => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            key={f}
            style={[
              styles.filterButton,
              filter === f && styles.activeFilter
            ]}
            onPress={() => {
              console.log(`Filter selected: ${f}`);
              setFilter(f);
            }}
          >
            <Text style={styles.filterText}>{f.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + f.slice(1)}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
      </View>

      <Text style={styles.subtitle}>Zelle Transactions</Text>
      <Text style={styles.balance}>${zelleBalance.toFixed(2)}</Text>

      <Button title="Paid out" onPress={handlePayout} />
      <Button title="Connect Bank" onPress={handleOpenLink} />

      {filterFromPayout && (
        <Text style={styles.payoutFilter}>
          From last paid out: {new Date(lastPayoutDate!).toLocaleString()}
        </Text>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 16,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginVertical: 8,
  },
  balance: {
    fontSize: 32,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginVertical: 8,
    color: '#4CAF50',
  },
  subtitle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: '600',
    marginTop: 16,
    marginBottom: 8,
  },
  filterContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    marginBottom: 16,
  },
  filterButton: {
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#E0E0E0',
  },
  activeFilter: {
    backgroundColor: '#4CAF50',
  },
  filterText: {
    color: '#000',
  },
  payoutFilter: {
    marginTop: 16,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#FF5722',
  },
});

export default BalancePage;

I've tried removing the onSuccess, but that doesnt work. I've tried using PlaidLink library, but that is deprecated. I've tried ChatGPT (lol) but that also just told me to add better logging to debug.
